# javascript check if string contains words in array and replace them

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble trying to check a string for words from an array and if it includes the word replace them.

```js
var blocked = [
  "inappropriate word one",
  "inappropriate word two",
];

var message = "the message has an inappropriate word one";

if (blocked.some(string => message.includes(string))) {
  message = message.replace(string, "blocked")
}
```

Comment: "string" is only available in the "some" method.  you will need to iterate the array of blocked words.

Comment: string is not accessible where you are using it, but why not loop over `blocked` array and call replace for each, replace will not work if the sentence doesn't exist, no need to pre-check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the body of the `if` the variable `string` is not available anymore because it's only valid in the callback of `some`. So just loop over the `blocked` words and do the replacement.

```
blocked.forEach(string => {
  if (message.includes(string)) message = message.replace(string, "blocked");
})
```

In principle the check isn't necessary. If the search value is not contained in the string, nothing will be replaced, so you can just do the following:

```
blocked.forEach(string => {
  message = message.replace(string, "blocked");
})
```

But be aware that [`String::replace(search, replacement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) only replaces the *first* occurence of `search` if it is a string. So if your "badword" occurs more than once, only the first occurence will be replaced. So it might be better to define your blocked words as regex, because this way you can replace multiple occurrences.

```
var replacements = [
  /badwordone/gi, 
  /badwordtwo/gi
]

replacements.forEach(r => { 
  message = message.replace(r, "blocked");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `message.replace(string)`, but `string` isn't defined outside the scope of that `some()` method. It is only available inside the `some()` method and is not available outside. Therefore your code doesn't work.

Comment: While it's correct, that `string` isn't availabe outside of the `some` method, your conclusions are rather strange. Because even if you assign something to a global variable within the callback of `some` this global variable can only contain a single value. So you will only be able to replace one of the blocked words ...

Comment: Oops. This was my first answer so sorry...